# How to convert escpaed unicode to emoji in javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter

From twitter feed I am getting below code. How to convert this twitter unicode to emoji in javascript?

`(&# 128079;&# 128079;&# 128079;&# 128079;)`

to

👏👏👏👏

How to show the emoji symobol using javascript?

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is remove the space; `feed.replace(/&#\s/g, "&#")`

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regex `/&# (\w+);/` to get each [Code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) to a capturing group. Then use [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) method in the replacement function of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to get the emojis like this:

```js
const str = '&# 128079;&# 128079;&# 128079;&# 128079;'
const emojiStr = str.replace(/&# (\w+);/g, (m, c1) => String.fromCodePoint(c1))

console.log(emojiStr)
```

([Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Hd4DH/1))

If you just want to display it on the DOM, you can just remove the space (`\s`) and set the *escaped* string to `innerHTML`

```js
const str = '&# 128079;&# 128079;&# 128079;&# 128079;'
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += str.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

```html
<span id='display'></span>
```